# How to accurately capture and store a name with pocketsphinx_continuous

Tags: voice-recognition, pocketsphinx

I'm working on a voice-recognition project and so far it's able to recognize a set of key-phrases I give it with pretty good accuracy. But what I wanted to do now was have a key-phrase say, "remember my name" that would trigger the `pocketsphinx_continuous` mode and capture that person's name and store it.

The problem is that running `pocketsphinx_continuous` mode is really innacurate when using the default dictionary. I want to know if there is a way of changing that default dictionary and replacing it with one containing names only, in hopes of improving the accuracy.

I'm also open to different suggestions :)

Comment: If you have custom dictionary you can use it with pocketsphinx_continuous using -dict option, you also need a custom language model with dict.
pocketsphinx_continuous -dict <custom dict path> -lm <custom LM path>

Comment: @G10DRAS Hi there, I took your advice and my code is almost working. I just don't know how to make a custom language model. Do you have anything I can maybe look at to figure that out ?

Comment: If your voab is not big you can try online lmtool (english only) http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html